# error: 'QByteArray::operator QNoImplicitBoolCast() const' is private

Tags: c++, qt

in a statement using exclusively standard C++ code, I get an error concerning QByteArray from the compiler (MinGW 5.3 32-bit - Windows 10)

the error is:
C:\Dev\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\include\QtCore\qbytearray.h:449: error: 'QByteArray::operator QNoImplicitBoolCast() const' is private
     operator QNoImplicitBoolCast() const

```
template<typename T>
inline QString getBitArrayString( T value )  // any length
{
    std::bitset<sizeof(T)*8> bs( value );            // ERROR

    return QString::fromStdString( bs.to_string() );
}
```

why do I get this error?
Is my statement wrong?

Thanks for your help.
Alain

Comment: Apparently this somehow got instantiated with `T==QByteArray`. It looks like it was intended only for fundamental integer types.  (Also, it would be better to use `CHAR_BIT` instead of `8`.)

Comment: thanks for CHAR_BIT advice.
I am wondering why T is seen as a QByteArray. Notice also, that the following code is compiled without problems:

'template<typename T>
inline T sq( T value ) { return (value * value); }'

Comment: `T` is seen as `QByteArray` because, in the code you haven't shown, you apparently call `getBitArrayString` with an argument of type `QByteArray`. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve].

Comment: yes, that was the reason! Thank you Igor.